# std::system stops when I tries to change jpg to mp4

Tags: ffmpeg, system, encode, mediapipe

I'm trying to use mediapipe Iris and I needed to make jpg to mp4 to use iris.

When I use image that has a person's face in it, system has no problem changing jpg to mp4 as below
[image]

However, if I put an image with no face or just an image as a background,
it stops and doesn't run to the other function anymore.
[image]

my code is

```
std::string Img2Vid(int i) {
  std::string input_path = FLAGS_input_video_path + "/" + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg";
  std::string output_path = FLAGS_input_video_path + "/" + std::to_string(i) + ".mp4";
  std::string s = "ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -t 0.07 -i " + input_path + " " + output_path;
  std::cout << output_path << std::endl;
  char ch[100];
  std::strcpy(ch, s.c_str());
  std::system(ch);
  return output_path;
  }
```

specifically, it should return output_path after changing jpg to mp4 like picture1, but it stucks at system(ch) when I run with image with no face.

Is there other way to change jpg to mp4 or to solve this problem?

Comment: This seems like an issue with `ffmpeg`, not your C++ code.

Comment: Does it work if you execute the same command by hand?

Comment: yes it happens when i use same command with different images

Comment: If it happens when you run the command by hand instead of from C++, why are you posting it as a C++ problem?

Comment: I thought the string or path would have the problems, so I posted C++

Comment: There's also no need for the `ch` array. Just use `system(s.c_str())`

Comment: *"However, if I put an image with no face or just an image as a background, it stops and doesn't run to the other function anymore."* Depending on your image format ffmpeg may not output a pixel format suitable for mediapipe Iris (whatever that is). Add `-vf format=yuv420p` output option to ffmpeg.

Comment: @llogan I tried "ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -t 0.07 -vf format=yuv402p -i ", "ffmpeg -vf format=yuv402p -loop 1 -f image2 -t 0.07 -i " and the other parts, it produces
_*Option vf (set video filters) cannot be applied to input url capture/0.jpg -- you are trying to apply an input option to an output file or vice versa. Move this option before the file it belongs to.
Error parsing options for input file capture/0.jpg*_....

Comment: @StevePark You are trying to apply an output option to an input file. `ffmpeg [input options] -i input [output options] output`. Also you have a typo. Change `yuv402p` to `yuv420p`

Comment: @llogan As your kindful comments, I could run the bazel and it shows
`deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly`
and it still doesn't proceed afterward. then I tried to use -pix_fmt yuv420p, and it also produces same comments and not running furthermore..

Comment: @StevePark `deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly` is not an error meant for users of the `ffmpeg` cli tool. Ignore it.  `-pix_fmt yuv420p` is just an alias for `-vf format=yuv420p`, so if `-vf format=yuv420p` doesn't help then neither will `-pix_fmt yuv420p`. I only suggested it as a potential easy fix. It was only a guess because you trimmed the log and only showed the last 15 lines. So the problem may not even be related to ffmpeg.

Comment: @llogan Thanks for your help. I'm sorry that I cannot post more codes to analysis the problem but you helped me a lot!